# How to refresh data from listview realtime

Tags: c#, listview, refresh

How can i refresh the data fetch in the listview  realtime?
when the event will come from another form
ex.

when i click the add button from form1 the details that are added will be reflected on form2 listview.

Comment: It\`s WinForms, right? Or WPF, or ASP.net? Better add a tag.

Comment: it is for winforms.. how can i do it? i have tried closing and opening the form that contains that listview inorder to of that container but i dont think it is a good way

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [ObservableCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which will raise events when the collection has changed and you can update your UI.